# R, mitools::MIcombine, what is the reason for no p-values?

Tags: r, linear-regression, summary, imputation, r-mice

I am currently running a simple linear regression model with 5 multiply imputed datasets in R.

E.g. `model <- with(imp, lm(outcome ~ exposure))`

To pool the summary estimates I could use the command `summary(mitools::MIcombine(model))` from the mitools package. However, this does not give results for p-values. I could also use the command `summary(pool(model))` from the mice package and this does give results for p-values.

Because of this, I am wondering if there is a specific reason why MIcombine does not produce p-values?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the documentation, it doesn't seem like there is a particular reason that the `mitools` library doesn't provide p-values. Although, the package's focus is on imputation, not model results.

However, you don't need either of these packages to see your results–along with the per model p-values. I started writing this as a comment but decided to include the code. If you weren't aware...you can use base R's `summary`. I realize that the output of `mice` is comparative, as is `mitools`. I thought it was important enough to mention this, as well.

If the output of your call is `model`, then this will work.

```
library(tidyverse)
map(1:length(model), ~summary(model[.x]))
```